# Satilla Shores unincorporated Glynn County

Tags: phrase-meaning

> An undated photo of Ahmaud Arbery
> Location:   Satilla Shores
> unincorporated Glynn County, Georgia, U.S.
> Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murder_of_Ahmaud_Arbery)

Does "Satilla Shores unincorporated Glynn County" mean "Satilla Shores (that is not included by) Glynn County"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means it's not governed by the municipality.

[USA Today](https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/2020/05/08/ahmaud-arbery-shooting-what-we-know-satilla-shores-community/3096389001/) says:

> Local officials say Satilla Shores, which is an unincorporated community in Glynn County, Georgia, has remained largely under the radar before the Feb. 23 slaying caught the national spotlight.

The term "unincorporated community" is then defined by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unincorporated_area):

> An **unincorporated area** is a region not governed by a local municipal corporation. Similarly, an **unincorporated community** is a settlement not governed by its own local municipal corporation, but is administered as part of larger administrative divisions, such as a township, parish, borough, county, city, canton, state, province, or country.

Answer (score 2):

Towns in the US are said to be incorporated so they can conduct business as an legal entity. Business like have employees or hire contractors to pave roads, etc. There should be a comma. If it is unincorporated, it cannot conduct business or have an elected town council, etc.

So, it should read:

Satilla Shores, unincorporated, Glynn County

**ALSO**:

An incorporated town or city in the United States is a municipality, that is, one with a charter received from the state. This is not to be confused with a chartered city/town with a governing system that is defined by the city's own charter document (voted in by its residents) rather than by state, provincial, regional or national laws. An incorporated town will have elected officials, as differentiated from an unincorporated community, which exists only by tradition and does not have elected officials at the town level.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incorporated_town)

Comment: You are correct that the location identifier needs **one** extra comma (so there is one comma between each location element). You have given it two. It should be: Satilla Shores, unincorporated Glynn County, Georgia. That is, "unincorporated Glynn County" is a distinct location—namely, all parts of Glynn County which have not been incorporated.

Comment: @randomhead Are you British? Counties in US states are **never** incorporated or unincorporated as they are state entities. Ergo, the term has to refer to the town and not the county. So, you are **mistaken**. Look at the other answer: they say Satilla Shores is a  **community**. Only it could be incorporated or unincorporated.

Comment: I am very much American. "Unincorporated Glynn County" means "some portion of Glynn County which is not incorporated into a town." Satilla Shores is an unincorporated community, and it is in Glynn County, and in order to avoid implying that it has been incorporated we specify that it is in *unincorporated* Glynn County.

Comment: @randomhead Portions of counties are not said to be unincorporated. Names of specific places are said to be one or the other.